# How can i make a levelsystem in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

The levelsystem only needs to work with JSON (simple)
So how can i safe points when a player sends a message? and write it down into a json format like this:

> {
> "userid":"0123456789"
> {
> "points":"0"
> {
> "level":"0"
> }
> } }

Comment: so i got the right format for json

{
    "userid":"0123456789",
        
            "points":"0",
                
                    "level":"0"
                
        
}

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using JSON for data that gets updated frequently. If you want to follow a JSON structure then you could use `pymongo` or `motor` which is a variation of pymongo but async.

You could use [this](https://github.com/PloxHost-LLC/community-bot/blob/main/cogs/leveling.py) as an example for creating a levelling system using pymongo/motor. You should add exp to a user, check if matches the algorithm if you need to update a level, either remove or keep the exp and then allow them to gain it. However, you do need to consider spam prevention which can be as simple as checking if a certain amount of time has passed like Mee6's.

Comment: i dont understand cogs rn gg